# Phoenix: Handle POST request body with Content-Type: application/json

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to handle an incoming POST with `application/json` content type. I am simply trying to return posted JSON as response to test like this:

**WebhookController controller**

```
pipeline :api do
  plug :accepts, ["json"]
end

def handle(conn, params) do
  {:ok, body, conn} = Plug.Conn.read_body(conn)    
  json(conn, %{body: body})
end
```

**router.ex**

```
scope "/webhook", MyApp do
  pipe_through :api

  post "/handle", WebhookController, :handle
end
```

If the incoming post has content type `application/json`, then body is empty. If the content type is `text` or `text/plain`, then body has the content.

**What is the right way to parse incoming `application/json` request body?**

I am using Phoenix 1.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When the Content-Type of the request is `application/json`, Plug parses the request body and Phoenix passes it as `params` to the controller action, so `params` should contain what you want and you don't need to read the body and decode it yourself:

```
def handle(conn, params) do
  json(conn, %{body: params})
end
```

```
$ curl -XPOST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary '{"foo": "bar"}' http://localhost:4000/handle
{"body":{"foo":"bar"}}
```

Comment: Please could you point to somewhere in the documentation or source code that explains this further?

Comment: @category check out https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/4a56d61d7046bccd2be9f7c953ba08c36dfda9a2/lib/plug/parsers.ex#L297 and https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/4a56d61d7046bccd2be9f7c953ba08c36dfda9a2/lib/plug/parsers/json.ex. Does this help?