# How to destructure/decode JSON within the function's arguments?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm very new to Elixir and am trying to build my first endpoint. I've just set up a new app with `mix phx.new` and have created my first controller.

```
defmodule AuthWeb.AuthController do
  use AuthWeb, :controller

  def login(conn, params) do
    IO.puts(inspect(params))
    redirect(conn, external: "https://google.com")
  end
end
```

With the config that you'd expect in `router.ex`, this works.

This endpoint is currently getting hit via the following `curl` command.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:4000/api/login -d '{"username": "foo", "password": "bar"}'
```

And I'd like to somehow destructure/decode this JSON in the arguments of the `login` function.

The `params` argument has the following value:

```
%{"{\"username\": \"foo\", \"password\": \"bar\"}" => "[FILTERED]"}
```

How would I be able to extract `username` and `password` bindings using pattern matching? What is the idiomatic way for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped me better understand the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41398480/1911755

I think the problem was that I was missing the content type header in the request.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:4000/api/login -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "foo", "password": "bar"}'
```

After adding it, the value of `params` became:

```
%{"password" => "[FILTERED]", "username" => "foo"}
```

which could be destructured like so:

```
def login(conn, %{"username" => username, "password" => password}) do
  IO.puts(inspect({username, password}))
  ...
end
```